# Domed concrete floor (garage) needs leveling

Tags: concrete, floor, level

I am about to replace a 14ft wide garage door. The concrete floor is domed in the centre of the doors width. The mid section of floor is roughly level for about 6 feet wide but falls away each side ending up about 20mm - 25mm lower. I want to level the two dropped areas up to the height of the top of the domed bit. Each dropped area will, when filled in, form a feathered edge on about half of the perimeter. I am about to start looking at the self leveling products now but I would appreciate advice regarding suitable type.

I plan to face the leading edge of the entire width with a piece of planed timber batten so that the timber is level with the uppermost area of domed floor. I then intend dropping some of the leveling product in each side and smooth them off level to the top of the timber batten and then feather the edges as best I can to get the entire width level.

Anyone have any tips, lifehacks or brilliant ideas that would improve on this approach. Also, what product type would you suggest as the leveling material?

A small (25-30cm) section of the leading edge of the garage floor in the mid section is also damaged. A small area about 50mm into the garage and to a depth of about 30mm has broken off. Would the leveling product be man enough (person enough?!) to act as a repair to the concrete?

Thanks in advance for your time and help

Best    Peter

Comment: I'd consider having a company come in and do a precision grind, creating a level shelf, instead. Your plan sounds like a hassle, will probably chip away over time, and may create unintended water drainage issues.

Comment: If you have not purchased the door yet you may want to consider a wood door. With a wood door you can cut the bottom to conform to the shape of the floor and then you combine that with a flexible seal at the bottom of the door.